# Why ecommerce tab not visible to create new page type with Kentico MVC 12?

Tags: kentico

I have an issue with the ecommerce module on Kentico MVC v12 with a fresh installation of DancingGoat(MVC) template.

My goal is to create a new type of product (different from Coffee and Brewer)

Here it says that we can create our own type of page and tranform them as product via the ecommerce tab:

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/e-commerce-features/configuring-your-store/configuring-product-page-types

What I should see:
[image]

What I see: (no ecommerce tab on the left)
[image]

I checked on the content module and I see a macro for a field called "Visible condition", is it why the tab is hidden ?
[image]

I'm connected as "administrator" so it should not be a problem of permissions.

Do you know how to make it visible ?

Comment: Are you connected as 'administrator' or as 'Global Administrator'? There is a difference. Maybe, as administrator, you do not have enough access rights.

Comment: I'm connected with username "administrator" but it's the "global administrator" account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing lots of tabs on the left like Fields, Layout, Alternative forms, Search as well. Make sure you macro signature is correct by going to System app > macro signature to resign them. Also make sure your hashsalt is the same in both Admin and MVC web.config.

Comment: I resigned the macros but nothing changed :x

Comment: Missing elements are typically caused by macro. Check the Event log app to see if there are any macro errors.

Comment: You were right ! I forgot to check "old salt", now I see them. Thank you very much !

Comment: Glad it's not something else we have to hunt for :)